# Mysql exception handling in stored procedure not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

mysql version : mysql  Ver 8.0.20 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

My procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InserirMedico(
    IN nome varchar(50),
    IN sexo char(1),
    IN nascimento date,
    IN id_horario int,
    IN vencimento int)
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062 SELECT 'Duplicate keys error encountered';
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1318 SELECT 'Incorrect number of arguments';
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1048 SELECT 'Invalid null field';
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1452 SELECT 'One or more foreign key constraints failed';
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 3819 SELECT 'One or more check constraints failed';
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1366 SELECT 'One or more columns has a incorrect data type';

        INSERT INTO medicos values (null, nome, sexo, nascimento, id_horario, vencimento);
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

My problem is that not all errors are being handled.
Error 1062,1366,1318 are not being handled and give me an error while the other ones are.
For example when i try to enter an invalid 'F' for "vencimento" field it gives me this error.

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'F' for column 'vencimento' at row 1
```

UPDATE* Provided missing info

```
create table horarios(
    id_horario int(3) primary key auto_increment,
    hora_inicio time not null,
    hora_fim time not null
);
```

```
create table medicos(
    id_med int primary key auto_increment,
    nome varchar(50) not null,
    sexo char(1) not null,
    data_nasc date not null,
    id_horario int not null,
    vencimento int not null,
    constraint fk_medicos_id_horario foreign key (id_horario) references horarios(id_horario),
    constraint CHK_medicos_ven check (vencimento > 0),
    constraint CHK_medicos_sexo CHECK (sexo IN('F','M'))
);
```

Testing the handlers

```
CALL InserirMedico("Mariana Venâncio", 'F', "1990:10:02",2,1000); /*Valid info*/
CALL InserirMedico("Mariana Venâncio", 'F', "1990:10:02",2,'F'); /*Error 1366*/
CALL InserirMedico("Mariana Venâncio", 'F', "1990:10:02",2);  /*Error 1318*/
```

Update2**
For error 1062

I have the following table

```
create table tipo_pagamento(
    cod_tipo char(1) primary key,
    descricao varchar(25) unique not null,
    estado bool not null
);
```

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InserirTipoDePagamento(
    IN cod_tipo char(1),
    IN descricao varchar(25),
    IN estado bool)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062 SELECT 'Duplicate keys error encountered';
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1048 SELECT 'Invalid null field';


        INSERT INTO tipo_pagamento VALUES (cod_tipo, descricao, estado);
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

```
CALL InserirTipoDePagamento('T', 'Teste', true);
```

Response:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'T' for key 'tipo_pagamento.PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Please create a full reproducible example with CREATE TABLE statement and the statements which raise the errors.

Comment: Do not use SELECT in exit handler - use CONTINUE handler, jump by error flag and  SIGNAL with reassigned MESSAGE_TEXT.

Comment: I have updated the question providing info to create the tables and my call statements.

Comment: 1366 and 1318 are raised by the procedure call - not by the INSERT inside the procedure. So you can't "catch" them. Please create an example for Error 1062

Comment: I have updated the question again giving an example for error 1062